# Search an array for a specific value

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to search an array to find `this._id`. `studentId returns` the correct Id however `fav returns` `Object {_id: "fMNS3M5dW356C46Sq", emails: Array[1], profile: Object, roles: Array[2]}`

How do I get `var fav` to return the `studentId` in the array or return null if the id isn't found?

Path: `list.js`

```
Template.list.events({
'click .favourite':function(event,template) {
      console.log('click');
        var studentId = this._id;
        var fav = Meteor.users.findOne({"profile.favorites":  studentId });

      console.log(fav);

        if (candidateId === fav) {
          Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$pull:{"profile.favorites":studentId}});
        } else {
          Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$push:{"profile.favorites":studentId}});
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you asking for fav to equal studentId if the findOne returns a user successfully?

Comment: Yes, if findOne finds an identical userId then fav should equal studentId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I think you want:

```
Template.list.events({
  'click .favourite':function(event,template) {
    console.log('click');
    var studentId = this._id;
    var fav = null;

    if( Meteor.users.findOne({"profile.favorites":  studentId }) ) {
      fav = studentId;
    }
    if (candidateId === fav) {
      Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$pull:{"profile.favorites":studentId}});
    } else {
      Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$push:{"profile.favorites":studentId}});
    };
  }
});
```

This will set fav to be the studentId if `Meteor.users.findOne` returns with something.

Comment: Yeah baby! You're the bomb mate!